# SAS: Loading built in dataset?

Tags: sas

I'm a complete SAS newbie, and I know that this is super basic, but I'm going crazy just trying to load the built in `sashelp.cars`, of course I can double click it and it loads but i can't figure out the syntax for it. This is what I already tried:

```
proc import out=sashelp.cars
datafile = 'SASHELP.CARS'
dbms = csv;
getnames = yes;
datarow = 2;
run;
```

Can anyone help with this? I'm using SAS on demand for academics. Thanks!

Comment: SASHELP.CARS is one of the many 'premade' data sets available to a SAS session.  They are created during SAS installation.  You can use them directly where ever you need to specify the data set to process. `Proc FREQ data=sashelp.cars;...`  , `Proc MEANS data=sashelp.shoes`, `Proc PRINT data=sashelp.class;...`  etc.  Use the SAS Explorer to drill to Libraries -> Sashelp to see a list of all the tables there.

Comment: Where are you trying to "load" it?  It should already be there, just reference it in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I get it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve,

Hard to know what you are asking for here. To get a dataset, especially one of the built-in ones, use this code:

```
   data test;    
      set sashelp.cars; 
   run;
```

Comment: Man you're a lifesaver. Could you maybe explain why my question was so unclear? I wanted to "load in" the cars data set which is a "built in" to sas dataset? I thought that was pretty clear. As I'm a total newbie I've almost certainly got the terminology wrong or I'm just not getting something here and so I would appreciate any feedback here as in what why I have conceptualized this incorrectly.

Comment: proc import is used for external data such as Excel/CSV/etc. Once it is inside of SAS, it is known as a dataset. SASHELP here refers to the libname (think directory). CARS is a file in that directory that has already been brought into SAS (the file ends in sas7bdat). Also, when you see me type using all caps it is because I used to be a mainframer, not a yelling symbol.

Comment: Also, a sas data step, like the above, is essentially a do loop. It reads read in the SAS dataset called cars from a directory called sashelp. Read it one record at a time and put it in the work library (again, it is a defined directory) and name the new file TEST. I like SHOES better than CARS but that is a preference. You should never write to SASHELP so don't do: data sashelp.cars; set test; run;. SASHELP is a very special directory (libname).